# Pymongo: find_one_and_update or update_one based on "custom" _id Object

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

this is the way one document looks like:

```
  {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ebe67974bfaadfe0ec3ed10"),
        "date" : 20180101,
        "likelybuy" : 1000614,
        "bixdemo_alter" : 2,
        "bixdemo_bundesland" : 10,
        "caseid" : 653433802,
        "bixdemo_haushalts_nettoeinkommen" : 2.0,
        "bixdemo_geschlecht" : 1,
        "sector" : 1026,
    }

coll.update_one({'_id': id},
        {
            '$set': {
              'sector': 1029,
        }
})
```

I can not use the "id_" to find the correct document, I have to use a combination of "date", "caseid" and "sector"

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure; you don't have to use an `_id` as a filter, you can use any fields. Just use those fields in the filter, e.g.

```
coll.update_one({'date': 20180101, 'caseid': 653433802,'sector': 1026},
        {
            '$set': {
              'sector': 1029,
        }
})
```

Comment: Wouldn't it fail, if there are other documents with same fields?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly match the `id`, instead of matching all other field's value. You can do the following:

Import `ObjectId`:

```py
from bson.objectid import ObjectId`
```

Do the query like:

```js
coll.update_one({'_id': ObjectId(id)},
        {
            '$set': {
              'sector': 1029,
        }
})
```

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I think you tried to find your id like:

```
coll.update_one({_id:'12314'},{})
```

but the problem is you pass string to search objectid.So, mongodb can not find it. If you try this below:

```
coll.update_one({_id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId('12314')},{})
```

It will work I think and also for combination search you can use '$elemMatch' in mongodb.